How to make object move in a parabolic arc in a certain amount of time?
I'm trying to make a script in Python where a certain sprite moves in a parabolic arc in a certain amount of time, where time = t. However I'm bad at this field of mathematics so I don't know how to properly code this, let alone make it happen in a certain amount of time.
First, I tried to make the y velocity slowly decrease as it reached the peak, and slowly increase after reaching the peak, like so:
# In pygame, the higher you go, the lower the y value. Smaller x values are to the left.
yvel = 1
if y > peak:
    y - yvel
    yvel -= 0.1
    x -= 2
else:
    y + yvel
    yvel += 0.1
    x -= 2

But I couldn't effectively control time and distance, and it also didn't look very smooth. Is there an equation I can use to simplify this, and make the object move over the entire parabolic arc in t time?

To make it smoother, use smaller increments for x and y in each step.

You should not flip any signs in an if/else statement. The y velocity should always increase in the same direction as gravity points, and the y position should always increase by the y velocity.

The y velocity should change at a constant rate.

For your intended purpose assuming constant horizontal velocity should be okay, thus you might use so-called Trajectory Formula which might be written in Python in the following way:
import math

def height(x, angle, velocity, gravity=9.8):
    return x * math.tan(angle) - (gravity * x ** 2) / (2 * velocity ** 2 * math.cos(angle) ** 2)

where angle and velocity pertains to angle of throw (radians) and initial velocity (meters per second), note that it assumes origin point (double zero) to be lower left corner.
For presentation sake, I created plot of that using seaborn in the following way:
import seaborn as sns

pos_x = list(range(10))
pos_y = [height(x, math.radians(45), 10) for x in pos_x]

sns.lineplot(x=pos_x, y=pos_y).get_figure().savefig('trajectory.png')

where angle is 45 degrees and initial velocity 10 meters per second, position is in meters.

If you need more smooth you should decrease step e.g. replace list(range(10)) using [i*0.1 for i in range(100)]. If you are wondering about 9.8, this is rough gravity acceleration found on Earth.


If you want the arc to take a fixed time then you need to set your initial y velocity (uy) to accommodate that. Google "projectile motion", or find a good mechanics textbook.
If tmax is the maximum time over horizontal ground then you need to set
uy=gtmax/2
where g is the acceleration due to gravity. In the absence of friction your x velocity would stay constant. You can just set a value of this to give a required maximum range in time tmax (i.e. ux=xmax/tmax) or, as here, you can set the initial angle from the horizontal (ux=uy/tan(angle)).
Your coordinates are then given as a function of time by
x=uxt,        y = uyt(1-t/tmax)
or you could choose to update them (and the y velocity) incrementally in time. Making them a function of time allows you to take them at equal intervals of time, which would make it more realistic.
How you animate it is up to you. I don't write games, so the following is done with matplotlib's FuncAnimation.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

g = 9.81                                                             # acceleration due to gravity (m/s^2)

n = 100         # number of time intervals
tmax = 12       # maximum time (s)
tantheta = 2    # initial gradient (tangent of angle from horizontal)

uy = g * tmax / 2
ux = uy / tantheta
xmax = ux * tmax
t = np.linspace( 0, tmax, 1 + n )
x = ux * t
y = uy * t * ( 1 - t/tmax )


def plot_animation( x, y ):
   fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize=(4,4) )
   ax.set_xlim( 0.0, xmax );   ax.set_ylim( 0.0, xmax );   ax.set_aspect('equal')
   point, = ax.plot( [x[0]], [y[0]], 'ro' ) 
   def animate( i ):                                                 # update anything that has changed
      point.set_xdata( [x[i]] )   
      point.set_ydata( [y[i]] )
   ani = animation.FuncAnimation( fig, animate, interval=10, frames=len( x ), repeat=True )
   plt.show()
#  ani.save( "demo.gif", fps=50 )

plot_animation( x, y )

